# What is the general solution of $xy=(x^2+4y)(dy/dx)?$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried to use u-substitution to separate the variables, as well as distributing $dy/dx$ as y' to $(x^2+4y)$.

However, I just can't seem to separate the variables no matter what methods I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

Transform the equation

$$xy + (-x^2-4y)y' = 0$$
into an exact one, using $R(x,y) = xy $ and $S(x,y) = -x^2-4y$. Continue with finding a $\mu(y)$ :

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg(\mu(y)R(x,y)\bigg) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\mu(y)S(x,y)\bigg)$$

You will then have the exact equation

$$\mu(y)R(x,y)  + y'\mu(y)S(x,y) = 0$$

which I assume you can handle, based on the exercise given to you.